# Load balancing between windows 2003 standard (4GB) and enterprise 64GB

Tags: windows-server-2003, load-balancing

Does anyone know if its possible to windows load balance between windows 2003 standard (4GB) and enterprise 64GB?

Its for a web farm running iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to have to say that I believe it's possible (never done it myself). This [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323437) details the steps required to configure Windows NLB on 2003 servers. In the 'applies to' section, all versions of 2003 Server are mentioned.

Comment: Definitely. If you run into any specific issues, feel free to continue to post on this question, and I'll do what I can to provide support!

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that standard NLB will not take into account the difference in server performance and you may end up hammering one server while the other is almost idle.

If the second server is for redundancy I would think about an active passive cluster rather than actual load balancing.

You can use ServerManagerCmd to install it from a command line, type “servermanagercmd –install nlb”

It can then be managed through admin tools / server manager.